# How can I fetch all tasks that are in backlog from Atlassian Jira Team-managed software Kanban Board with Python or Rest?

Tags: python, jira

I have a Kanban board at
https://mycompany.atlassian.net/jira/software/projects/GENERAL/boards/3

It has the following features:

- Type: Team-managed software
- Timeline: On
- Backlog: On
- Board: On
- Reports: On
- Issue navigatior: Off
- Sprints: Off
- Estimation: Off
- Development code, security, releases: Off
- Opeartions Deployment, On-call: Off
- More items Project pages: off

When I create a task it gets the Status="To Do".

It gets this even if it is placed in the Backlog.

As an example I got two cases, one in the Board and one in the Backlog: They are the same when I get them with Python and the rest API.

My question is how can I determine if a task is located in the backlog or in the Board?

This is my Python code to fetch tasks:

```
# Connect
jira_workspace_email = "x@y.com"
jira_api_token = "ABC"
jira_options = {'server': "https://mycompany.atlassian.net"}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=(jira_workspace_email, jira_api_token))


# Fetch tasks
for singleIssue in jira.search_issues(jql_str=f"project = GENERAL order by updated"):
    task_external_id = singleIssue.key
    raw_fields_json = singleIssue.raw['fields']

    f = open(f"tmp/jira_{task_external_id}.json", "w")
    f.write(json.dumps(raw_fields_json, indent=4))
    f.close()
```

Example of output of "raw_fields_json":

```
{
    "statuscategorychangedate": "2023-08-20T00:21:08.205+0200",
    "fixVersions": [],
    "customfield_10198": null,
    "customfield_10110": null,
    "customfield_10111": null,
    "customfield_10199": null,
    "resolution": null,
    "customfield_10112": [],
    "customfield_10104": null,
    "customfield_10105": null,
    "customfield_10106": null,
    "customfield_10107": null,
    "customfield_12345": null,
    "customfield_10109": null,
    "lastViewed": "2023-08-20T00:21:37.784+0200",
    "customfield_10180": null,
    "customfield_10181": null,
    "customfield_10182": null,
    "customfield_10183": null,
    "customfield_10184": null,
    "customfield_10185": null,
    "customfield_10187": null,
    "priority": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3",
        "iconUrl": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
        "name": "MEDIUM",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "customfield_10100": [],
    "labels": [],
    "customfield_10103": null,
    "customfield_10215": null,
    "customfield_10216": null,
    "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": null,
    "timeestimate": null,
    "versions": [],
    "issuelinks": [],
    "assignee": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=x",
        "accountId": "x",
        "emailAddress": "mrx@mycompany.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/48",
            "24x24": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/24",
            "16x16": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/16",
            "32x32": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/32"
        },
        "displayName": "Mr X",
        "active": true,
        "timeZone": "Europe/Oslo",
        "accountType": "atlassian"
    },
    "status": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10149",
        "description": "",
        "iconUrl": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/",
        "name": "To do",
        "id": "10149",
        "statusCategory": {
            "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
            "id": 4,
            "key": "indeterminate",
            "colorName": "yellow",
            "name": "In Progress"
        }
    },
    "components": [],
    "customfield_10170": null,
    "customfield_10174": null,
    "customfield_10175": null,
    "customfield_10177": null,
    "customfield_10178": null,
    "customfield_10179": null,
    "aggregatetimeestimate": null,
    "creator": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=x",
        "accountId": "x",
        "emailAddress": "mrx@mycompany.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/48",
            "24x24": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/24",
            "16x16": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/16",
            "32x32": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/32"
        },
        "displayName": "Mr X",
        "active": true,
        "timeZone": "Europe/Oslo",
        "accountType": "atlassian"
    },
    "subtasks": [],
    "customfield_10160": null,
    "customfield_10163": null,
    "reporter": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=x",
        "accountId": "x",
        "emailAddress": "mrx@mycompany.com",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/48",
            "24x24": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/24",
            "16x16": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/16",
            "32x32": "https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/x/ffa95385-b6c3-4074-b732-5e7f7b3e436a/32"
        },
        "displayName": "Mr X",
        "active": true,
        "timeZone": "Europe/Oslo",
        "accountType": "atlassian"
    },
    "aggregateprogress": {
        "progress": 0,
        "total": 0
    },
    "customfield_10200": null,
    "customfield_10201": null,
    "customfield_10169": null,
    "customfield_10202": null,
    "progress": {
        "progress": 0,
        "total": 0
    },
    "votes": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/GENERAL-478/votes",
        "votes": 0,
        "hasVoted": false
    },
    "worklog": {
        "startAt": 0,
        "maxResults": 20,
        "total": 0,
        "worklogs": []
    },
    "issuetype": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10130",
        "id": "10130",
        "description": "Tasks track small, distinct pieces of work.",
        "iconUrl": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/universal_avatar/view/type/issuetype/avatar/10318?size=medium",
        "name": "Task",
        "subtask": false,
        "avatarId": 10318,
        "entityId": "x-y-4ed4-897d-d26a7e2180ce",
        "hierarchyLevel": 0
    },
    "timespent": null,
    "project": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/12345",
        "id": "12345",
        "key": "GENERAL",
        "name": "General Board",
        "projectTypeKey": "software",
        "simplified": true,
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/universal_avatar/view/type/project/avatar/10421",
            "24x24": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/universal_avatar/view/type/project/avatar/10421?size=small",
            "16x16": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/universal_avatar/view/type/project/avatar/10421?size=xsmall",
            "32x32": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/universal_avatar/view/type/project/avatar/10421?size=medium"
        }
    },
    "customfield_10031": null,
    "aggregatetimespent": null,
    "customfield_10027": null,
    "customfield_10028": null,
    "customfield_10029": null,
    "resolutiondate": null,
    "workratio": -1,
    "issuerestriction": {
        "issuerestrictions": {},
        "shouldDisplay": true
    },
    "watches": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/GENERAL-478/watchers",
        "watchCount": 1,
        "isWatching": true
    },
    "created": "2023-08-20T00:21:07.763+0200",
    "customfield_10020": null,
    "customfield_10021": null,
    "customfield_10022": null,
    "customfield_10023": null,
    "customfield_10024": null,
    "customfield_10025": null,
    "customfield_10026": null,
    "customfield_10016": null,
    "customfield_10017": null,
    "customfield_10018": {
        "hasEpicLinkFieldDependency": true,
        "showField": true,
        "nonEditableReason": {
            "reason": "PLUGIN_LICENSE_ERROR",
            "message": "The Parent Link is only available to Jira Premium users."
        }
    },
    "customfield_10019": "0|i02t7j:",
    "updated": "2023-08-20T00:21:40.625+0200",
    "timeoriginalestimate": null,
    "description": null,
    "customfield_10010": null,
    "customfield_10014": null,
    "customfield_10015": null,
    "timetracking": {},
    "customfield_10126": null,
    "customfield_10005": null,
    "customfield_10127": null,
    "customfield_10006": null,
    "customfield_10128": null,
    "security": null,
    "customfield_10007": null,
    "customfield_10129": null,
    "customfield_10008": null,
    "attachment": [],
    "customfield_10009": null,
    "summary": "mrx test To Do",
    "customfield_10120": null,
    "customfield_10121": null,
    "customfield_10000": "{}",
    "customfield_10122": null,
    "customfield_10001": null,
    "customfield_10123": null,
    "customfield_10002": null,
    "customfield_10003": null,
    "customfield_10124": null,
    "customfield_10125": null,
    "customfield_10116": null,
    "environment": null,
    "customfield_10117": null,
    "customfield_10118": null,
    "customfield_10119": null,
    "duedate": null,
    "comment": {
        "comments": [],
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/27037/comment",
        "maxResults": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "startAt": 0
    }
}
```

The status is "To do"

```
"status": {
    "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10149",
    "description": "",
    "iconUrl": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/",
    "name": "To do",
    "id": "10149",
    "statusCategory": {
        "self": "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
        "id": 4,
        "key": "indeterminate",
        "colorName": "yellow",
        "name": "In Progress"
    }
},
```